# Can't assign custom class to Page View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I'm using storyboard and I added a Page View Controller, which now I want to configure to use my own custom class. For this, I select the page view controller which is indicating to use UIPageViewController in Custom Class under the Identity Inspector. I set my own, WinkPageViewController, but I get a "bump" sound and deselecting + selecting the view controller again shows the property has been reset to the previous value.

I'm not sure what parts of the code would be relevant, so I'll leave the interface here, for now, but please let me know if anything else is relevant for this.

```
@interface WinkPageViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPageViewController* pageViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) WinkPageModelController* modelController;

//// Sent when a gesture-initiated transition begins.
//- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
//
//// Sent when a gesture-initiated transition ends. The 'finished' parameter indicates whether the animation finished, while the 'completed' parameter indicates whether the transition completed or bailed out (if the user let go early).
//- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed;
//
//// Delegate may specify a different spine location for after the interface orientation change. Only sent for transition style 'UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl'.
//// Delegate may set new view controllers or update double-sided state within this method's implementation as well.
//- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation;
//
//- (NSUInteger)pageViewControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
//- (UIInterfaceOrientation)pageViewControllerPreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);

- (WinkOAuthProfileProviderIdentifier)profileProviderPreference;
- (void)saveProfileProviderPreference:(WinkOAuthProfileProviderIdentifier)preference;
- (NSURL*)profileURLWithProviderIdentifier:(WinkOAuthProfileProviderIdentifier)provider error:(NSError**)error;
- (void)saveProfile:(WinkProfile*)profile error:(NSError**)error;
- (WinkProfileData*)loadProfileWithProviderIdentifier:(WinkOAuthProfileProviderIdentifier)provider error:(NSError**)error;

- (void)didReceiveProfile:(WinkProfile*)profile;

@end
```

I know I'm not implemented the UIPageViewControllerDelegate optional methods (which happens to be all of them), but I have done this before in swift and it worked. What should I do?

Comment: I assume that you have implemented `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` somewhere else, too, right?

Comment: Yes. `WinkPageModelController` implements that protocol. That's the `modelController` property in the code I posted

Comment: By the way, I have two more view controllers (not page view controllers) in my scene and they both have custom classes. That much works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A square is a rectangle, but a rectangle might not be a square

*Page View Controller* (from the Object library in a Storyboard) represents `UIPageViewController`.

*View Controller* (from the Object library in a Storyboard) represents `UIViewController`.

`WinkPageViewController` inherits from `UIViewController` and cannot represent the custom class of a *Page View Controller* object.

---

**UIPageViewController Class Reference**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

Comment: So simple. I would not have guessed for one reason: If I wrote *anything* else in there, it compiled. And I mean just random text. So it allows for non-existant identifiers, but doesn't allow for identifiers which do not match certain criteria. It's good to know. Thank you.